# parse decimal string with sscanf

Tags: c, linux, glibc, scanf

I want to parse string to integer. 
The string can contain any data, including invalid or float integers. This is my code which shows how I'm using `sscanf()`:

```
errno = 0;
uint32_t temp;
int res = sscanf(string, "%"SCNu32, &temp);
if (0 != errno || 1 != res)
{
    return HEX_ECONVERSION;
}
```

where string passed as argument.

I've expected that this code would fail on `"3.5"` data. But unfortunately, `sscanf()` truncate `"3.5"` to `3` and write it to `temp` integer.
What's wrong?

Am I improperly using `sscanf()`? And how to achieve this task by using `sscanf`, without writing hand-written parser (by directly calling `strtoul()` or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `"%n"` records where the scan is in the buffer.
We can use it to determine what stopped the scan.

```
int n;
int res = sscanf(string, "%"SCNu32 " %n", &temp, &n);
if (0 != errno || 1 != res || string[n] != '\0')
  return HEX_ECONVERSION;
```

Appending `" %n"` says to ignore following white-space, then note the buffer position.  If there is not additional junk like `".5"`, the `string[n]` will point to the null terminator.

---

Be sure to test `n` after insuring `temp` was set.  This was done above with `1 != res`.

`"%n"` does not affect the value returned by `sscanf()`.

Comment: I see that here you even no need to test `1 != res` as if string is fully consumed `string[n]` will point to `'\0'` always, on another case, doesn't matter which value has `res` it will be error. Am I right?

Comment: @likern By first testing `res` in `... 1 != res || string[n] != '\0'`, we know `string[n] != '\0'` will only get executed if `res` had the value 1.  So we know the scan conversion made it through `"%"SCNu32`.  Scan conversion never stops on the `" "` in `" %n"`, so it is known the scanning reach `"%n"` and `n` has a legitimate value.  Should `res < 1`, then the scan never went pass `"%"SCNu32` and therefore `sscanf()` did not set `n`.  But maybe I am missing your point?

Comment: No, probably I just was wrong. I thought that I can just remove `1 != res` checking when `string[n] != '\0'` is used.

Comment: @likern  Code _can_ follow your new idea by `int n = 0;` and later `if (0 != errno || n > 0 || string[n] != '\0')` but this does not save much and loses the EOF detection.  Your `if (...  || 1 != res || ...)` is better.

Answer (score 4):

`3` is a valid integer.  Unfortunately `sscanf` is not complicated enough to look ahead and detect that `3.5` is a `float` and not give you any result.

Try using `strtol` and testing the return pointer to see if it parsed the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf` only parses the part of the string that it can. You can add another format to it such as `"%d%s"`. If the `%s` specifier captures a non-empty string (such as `.5`), throw an error.

Comment: Does this mean that `sscanf()` even doesn't indicate `error`? Only by using some tricky like "%d%s"?

Comment: Extra characters after a valid string isn't an error.